# Проблема запуска приложения Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

При помощи Android Studio - написал небольшое приложение. При старте через AS - все ок - и в эмуляторе и на смартфоне. Далее - я выгружаю apk файл в firebase console -> app distribution - и через него даю возможность установить приложение тестерам - но программа, на смартфоне не стартует - появляется начальный экран - а потом сообщение о сбое - и все. Что конкретно сбоит - не ясно. При этом - таким способом я уже выгружал и все было норм. Пробовал откатывать изменения - не помогает. Есть идеи - в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: https://blog.codemagic.io/deploying-flutter-app-to-firebase-app-distribution-using-fastlane/

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать подключить **crashlytics** и посмотреть там логи
[Документация](https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]